# Milarepa and Avalokiteshvara practice

Tags: vajrayana, avalokitesvara

In the Vajrayana tradition, where did Milarepa state that it was possible to use the practice of Chenrézik (Avalokiteshvara) instead of the one of Hevajra?

Answer (score 1):

There is a qualitative difference between a practice which *uses* Avalokitasvara (Chenrezig) for visualizations, etc., and the practice that was used *by* Avalokitasvara to reach enlightenment. They are not the same.

The Mahayana/Vajrayna Surangama Sutra is of immeasurable value in this regard. It describes this path, which was taken by Buddha and Manjusri, as well as Avalokitasvara, and all Buddhas. See Manjushri’s Summation from the Surangama Sutra: https://bit.ly/ManjushriSummation

Jamyang Khyentse Chökyi Lodrö’s “The Light That Makes Things Clear: A Prophecy of Things to Come,” (“ma 'ongs lung bstan gsal byed sgron me zhes bya ba bzhugs so”) indicates this meditation method is the one most useful for beings such as we, in the Dharma ending time. See: http://bit.ly/TheLightThatMakesThingsClear

Using this method with the support of inner spontaneous sounds* results in the accomplishment of Great Responsiveness (Mahakaruna) and the supreme siddhi.

There is a universal understanding of this path. See: http://bit.ly/PathToEnlightenment

The Tibetan Nyingma teacher, Khenpo Sodargye Rinpoche, is teaching the Surangama Sutra at the Larung Gar center, in Sêrtar County of Garzê Tibetan Autonomous Prefecture, in Sichuan, China, also known as Kham, which he is the head of, since late 2019.

The english translations of those teachings are on Youtube. This is the webpage announcing his teachings: http://khenposodargye.org/teachings/khenpos-classical-teachings/surangama-sutra/

Note: many traditions use inner spontaneous sounds to different purposes and with different interpretations. Here are a list of keywords to search with: Abstract Sound, Astral Sound, Anāhata Nāda, Dharma Sound of the Diamond Samadhi, Chönyid kyi rangdra (Chos Nyid Kyi Rang Sgra), Dharmata Swayambhu Nada, Divine Tremoring, Eternal Sound, Holy Stream of Sound, Inner sacred sound, Inner Sound, Music of the Spheres, Nada-Brahman, Omkara Dhvarni, Primordial Sound, Resonance of Emptiness, Sawt-e-sarmad, Sacred Sound, Shabda, Shabda Brahman, Sound of Creation, Sound of Silence, Soundless Sound, Thunder of Silence, Transcendental Sound, Unborn Sound, Unstruck Sound, Word of God.

Comment: Thank yo for the asnwer , but it doesn not answer to it. I edited the question to be more clear on the topic.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I edited your question so it is clearer.

Comment: That sounds like a more human English :D

Answer (score 0):

Taking good care of oneself is such a practice; Gotama practiced such a thing with the simple smile asana as taking good care of others seen and unseen. The concept of Metta or loving/kindness there is a Germanic influence in the word "Kindness" as it means the kindred of home and hearth; feng shui is a connection to that philosophy as well.

Lots of stuff to study and yet simply doing; minding the flow of energy without becoming too big a rock in the rakes path.

That's a suggested course; here's as requested link wise https://www.samyeling.org/buddhism-and-meditation/teaching-archive-2/dharmacharya-ken-holmes/chenrezik-bodhisattva-of-compassion/

http://www.lamakathy.net/resources/pdf/chenrezig_shortB4.pdf

The simple smile btw alerts one to the various bhavas or realms of becoming one is passing through; when the divine ear hears insult about the smile? It is either a masters praise like a twinkle in the eye or outright rebuke from jealousy etc. anyways just keep smiling... Best to try to catch that monkey smile when it arises on it's own and yoke it then; you'll be riding that Ox home.